# Should I export images with exposure for websites? If no then how can I set the exposure, offset and gamma correction value to css?

Tags: html, css, photoshop

Should I export images with exposure for websites? If no then how can I set the exposure, offset and gamma correction values to css?

My images in psd file has exposure outside the images group that is affecting the images. When I double click on the exposure, I see, exposure has a value of -0.60, offset has +0.0150 and gamma correction has 1.00. How can I achieve the exposure effect with css? How much black or bright it will be? Please provide a formula so that I can set an overlay image over the original images.

Also tell me, what is exposure, offset and gamma correction? What does exposures do? I am using photoshop version 21.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

There are filter functions available in css:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function

I suggest playing around with them until you receive the desired effect. (there's an interactive demo on the page above)

However, do not expect to get the same kind of fine-tuning as in photoshop.